# How to filter results in HERE v7 reverse-geocode API

Tags: here-api

i'm working on the migration of HERE geocoder API from v6 to v7.

Speaking of reverse-geocode, the v6 had a parameter ('mode') to filter the results types to be street-addresses, administrative-areas, or landmarks, and v6 had no Places resources.

The new API v7 has not such a filter parameter, so the result list is a mixed bag of street addresses, administrative-areas, landmarks and places. I can work this by consuming more results and filtering out the unwantend ones, but this does not guarantee to have the desired type of results.

So, is there a parameter (undocumented or in the works) to have v7 to behave like v6 to filter a specific result type?

Best,
Mauro